# Printing to a dot matrix printer from a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, printing

I'm looking to print reports from a rails 4 web app to a dot matrix printer.
I tried exporting to a text file and printing it, but no luck.. i.e. it did not look, feel and behave the same.
The rationale for doing this is printing large reports quickly using existing infrastructure that the client has.

Appreciate any help I can get......

Thanks!

Comment: *"look, feel and behave"* - the printout didn't feel and behave as expected? Please elaborate.

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting and what you are getting. Also some example code would help

Comment: To the look, feel and behave aspect, the compression (no of characters per line) was not as expected when comparing to an existing dot matrix report - the charters were more spread out.

Comment: In terms of sample code, I can export as CSV, write to a txt file, the question is, is there a way to write to a file in ASCII mode?

Comment: Is the printer connected to the server (where the app is running) or to the client?

Comment: Stefan - Its connected to the client - so need to download an ascii encoded file... ( unless there is another way to do it)

Comment: What is an "ascii encoded file"?

Comment: Looks like  opening the file in binary mode works..... that being said....the file needs to be opened in dos mode  'edit <filename>' before printing. If it's opened in notepad, the result will not be as expected